# Regex expression 32 alphanumeric and special char

Tags: regex

I'm not an expert in regex and I'm stuck because online regex validators do not match my string.

I need a regular expression for checking a 32 character alphanumeric string containing one special character.

I've tried this but it is not working:

```
^((?=.*[\W]{1})[a_zA_Z0_9].{32,32})$
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Thé spécial char could be anywhere?

Comment: Yes in every position is okay

Comment: w* is for alphanuméric . W is for non alphanuméric. So (w* W w*){32} could work

Comment: You need to replace `_` in ranges with `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a range inside a character class is defined with a `-`, not `_`. Also, it is not necessary to use `{1}`, each atom is matched once by default (`c` in regex only matches 1 `c`). If you need to match a precise amount of chars, use a `{m}` limiting quantifier form, so `{32}` = `{32,32}`. Also, you quantified `.`, `.{32,32}`, and that means you allow any 32 chars other than line break chars in the input string, but it should start with an alphanumeric char (`[a_zA_Z0_9]`) and must contain at least 1 non-word char (`(?=.*[\W]{1})`).

You need to use

```
^(?=.{32}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\W[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4bfZS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{32}$)` - 32 chars are required
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `\W` - a non-word char (or `[\W_]` to also support a `_`)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string